# How to ensure structs implement functions consistently, without callers having to explicitly 'use' the trait?

Tags: rust, traits

Given multiple similar structs, it may be useful to implement functions matching a signature.

The simple example below works nicely, but doesn't ensure all functions follow the same function signature.

```
impl FooStruct {
    pub fn calc_value(seed: i64) -> i64 { /* function body! */ }
}
impl BarStruct {
    pub fn calc_value(seed: i64) -> i64 { /* function body! */ }
}
```

Using a trait resolves this:

```
pub trait CanCalcValue {
    fn calc_value(seed: i64) -> i64;        
}

impl CanCalcValue for FooStruct {
    fn calc_value(seed: i64) -> i64 { /* function body! */ }
}
impl CanCalcValue for BarStruct {
    fn calc_value(seed: i64) -> i64 { /* function body! */ }
}
```

However, now I have to add `use some_module::CanCalcValue;` everywhere I wan't to call `calc_value`.

Is there some way to define a trait that can be used without having to ensure it's in the namespace?

Said differently, there are times when logically a trait makes sense in that multiple structs share a signature, but I avoid using it because it becomes annoying to have to `use` the trait all over the codebase.

---

**Note:** there is discussion on this topic in the [RFC issue tracker](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1880), although no RFC currently.

Comment: I suppose that you are invoking those methods from macros? Because that's the only way to have polymorphism without traits.

Comment: Yes, from macros or just in regular code, where its convenient from a user-pov to know there is consistency in the API even though its not necessarily required.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there some way to define a trait that can be used without having to ensure its in the name-space?

In short, no. To use a trait, you must import it. Without a trait, you can't ensure that the signatures are the same.

Comment: Turns out there is an `RFC` for this: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1880 - worth adding to answer?

Comment: That's not an RFC; it's an issue on the tracker. I don't think it's worth changing the answer until it's actually in the language, rather than a random idea proposed.

Comment: Ah right, even so - anyone stumbling on this page may be interested to know Rust developers are aware of this and the suggestion has been made - I've linked to it in the question.

Comment: It would also seem like a bad idea.  What if another trait somewhere else also provided `calc_value`?  At some point you have to explicitly say which trait is involved.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson: Making common things easy and rare things possible is a great UI principle; it means that you could say that if `calc_value` is defined by an impl in the same module as the current trait, it's automatically picked up, unless there's a conflict in which case the user has to specify the intent.

Comment: @MatthieuM. True, and maybe that's fine as long as it's local like that.  Personally I think there's a risk that special-cased conveniences like that can accumulate and interact into hard to understand behaviour.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson: It's definitely a risk. It increases the number of rules to remember (eating at the complexity budget). It's also backward incompatible.